# Alternative Implementation for scala.concurrent.Future?

Tags: scala

Given two `Future[Option[Int]]`:

```
scala> val x: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful { None }
x: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@39dcf4b0

scala> val y: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful { Some(55) }
y: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$KeptPromise@7ef2d7a6
```

Is there a cleaner way to do the following?

```
scala> def f[A](x: Future[Option[A]], 
                y: Future[Option[A]]): Future[Option[A]] = x.flatMap( _ match {
     |   case None => y
     |   case Some(_) => x
     | })
f: [A](x: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[A]], y: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[A]])scala.concurrent.Future[Option[A]]
```

I thought of using an Alternative, but I'm not sure of such an implementation of `scala.concurrent.Future`:

```
>import Control.Applicative
> Nothing <|> Just 55
Just 55
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following mechanism:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, duration, ExecutionContext, Future}
import duration.Duration
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val f = Future.reduce(Seq(x, y))(_ orElse _)
Await.result(f, Duration.Inf) // Some(55)
```

Or if the number of options in unclear, use `Future.fold` with a zero of `Option.empty[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using scalaz, you can use a monad transformer even if it's a bit overkill for such a simple example.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scalaz.OptionT
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture.futureInstance

def f[A](x: Future[Option[A]],
         y: Future[Option[A]]): Future[Option[A]] = 
  OptionT(x).orElse(OptionT(y)).run
```

Also, the `_ match` part of your function was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In scala 2.13 you could simplify your case with zipWith

```
x.zipWith(y)(_ orElse _)
```

Or use zip in lower versions

```
x.zip(y).map { case (xVal, yVal) => xVal orElse yVal }
```