# Reducing two futures of options with _ orElse _ does not yield Some

Tags: scala, future

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686590/alternative-implementation-for-scala-concurrent-future), I thought the following is a solution:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

val x: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful { None }
val y: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.successful { Some(55) }

Future.reduce(Seq(x, y))(_ orElse _).value  // expecting Some(Success(Some(55)))
```

To my surprise, executing this in a REPL mostly gives `None` with erratically giving `Some(55)`:

```
res80: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = None
res81: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = None
res82: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = None
res83: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = Some(Success(Some(55)))
res84: Option[scala.util.Try[Option[Int]]] = None
```

So this a Scala WTF moment for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smaller code has the same result: `Future(42).value` (sometimes print `None`).

Actually the problem is how you use the `value` method (from the scaladoc):

> If the future is not completed the returned value will be `None`.

You need to await the future if you want to be sure that it will yield a value.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently it doesn't matter that both futures have completed, the default execution context may still decide to spawn the resulting future, so it may only complete shortly after.

```
Await.result(Future.reduce(Seq(x, y))(_ orElse _), Duration.Inf) // Some(55)
```

Comment: Indeed. It doesn't matter whether the other futures are completed because the reduction could itself take some time, so the operation would block if it computed it directly.  Thus, in keeping with Future's rather aggressively non-blocking API, it must spawn the computation.